# Change windows 7 as the primary bootloader

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7, windows-8-preview, bootloader

Uh, I'll first tell you the history of OS Changes that have ever occurred to my computer :

- First I installed Windows 7 on a partition (333 GB).
- Next after Windows 8 Consumer Preview was released, I shrunk that partition and created another 80 GB partition out of the 333 GB one and installed Win 8 in that. This provided me with options for dual-boot. All was fine.
- Next, I don't know why, but I installed Ubuntu by formatting the Win 8 partition. Then grub did not even recognize the Win 7 Partition.
- So I re-installed Win 8 (out of desperation, because I want Win 7 back badly) so that I could be back to the previous state. But after booting into the DVD and installing on the Ubuntu partition, the second part of the installation did not even complete (i.e Windows is usually installed in 2 parts. The second part is completed after a reboot)
- Since the installation did not complete, I re-installed Ubuntu on the 80 GB partition. And it now goes into GRUB with Ubuntu and Windows Vista Boot Loader ! I go into that partition and it just prints a few non ASCII chars and justs hangs !

Please guys help me out....I don't even want the Ubuntu partition... Anything to get the 253 GB Win 7 Partition (it is totally untouched) back to how it was. Would a repair do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Bootrec.exe? It's a tool provided by microsoft and it should be present on any Windows 7 install DVD. [see "support.microsoft.com"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)

Comment: I can't (I didn't know of it though). I am on ubuntu. And thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Any such Ubuntu tool ? I don't mind losing anything except for the Windows partition. I just want it to load at startup. Don't mind losing Ubuntu. I could always use virtual box.

Comment: The program can be booted from windows DVD, you don't need to have Windows booting from Harddisk in order to use it. Can you set the boot order in the BIOS so that the DVD/CD is launched before Harddrive? Then you can insert the Setup DVD, reboot the computer and you should be in Windows setup/recovery/repair.

Comment: Yeah, I can change the Boot order, but how exactly do I start the recovery process ?

Comment: And will a Windows 7 Professional installation Disc repair (I am having Windows 7 Ultimate in the hard disk)

Comment: Yeah, it should work on professional or ultimate the same way. It works basically the same way as you install a new system. On startup, it asks you to press any key to boot from CD/DVD. After the DVD has loaded, there is a repair/recovery option. The Link I gave you (microsoft support) has detailled information on this. Good luck!

Comment: And my second question ? Windows 7 Professional to repair Windows 7 Ultimate ?

Comment: Shouldn't matter, since you only repair the boot record. Any version of win 7 will do.

Comment: Glad if I can help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you still need help with this, you can use [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/boot-repair) to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Well, its been over a year, so I most probably got the problem solved. But yeah, would be useful for the community...